# Making a customized schedule in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm new to vs10 and I'm trying to make a customized schedule/calender using WPF. So far I have somewhat of a visual. I'm using a grid with rectangles and separators to make the grid lines. What I'm confused on is how I can make every month. I want to be able to have two arrow buttons switching between months but I'm not sure what I can do to make the correct dates to appear where they should be. I was going to use buttons to display each date on the calender so when the user clicks on it he/she can add an event/appointment for that particular day/date. Any advice or tips is greatly appreciated.

```
    Page x:Class="Camp_.SchedulePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="315" d:DesignWidth="587"
Title="schedulePage" Background="#FF0A0A0A">
<Grid Width="Auto">
    <Calendar Height="174" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,78,0,0" Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC3D6F5" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEFF5FF" Offset="1" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="98,60,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" OpacityMask="Black" Opacity="1" Background="#FFC2ECEC" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.Resources>  <Style x:Key="VerticalSeparatorStyle" 
   TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Separator}}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                <TransformCollection>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TransformCollection>
                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Separator Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="separator4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Aqua" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Aqua" OpacityMask="Aqua" />
            <Separator  Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="separator2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Background="Aqua" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Aqua" />
            <Separator Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="separator1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Aqua" />
            <Separator Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="separator3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Aqua" />

            <Rectangle Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="5" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle3" Stroke="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle4" Stroke="Aqua" Grid.Column="3" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle5" Stroke="Aqua" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle6" Stroke="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="5" />
            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectangle7" Stroke="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="6" />
            <Button Content="1" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
            <Button Content="2" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
        </Grid>



        <Grid Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="98,31,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Sunday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Label Content="Monday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Content="Tuesday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Label Content="Wednesday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,68,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Label Content="Thursday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,2,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" />
            <Label Content="Friday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" />
            <Label Content="Saturday" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6" />
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="&gt;" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,6,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" />
        <Button Content="&lt;" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,8,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I would bind a list of `Day` objects to an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsPanel` is set to a `Grid` with 6 rows, and 7 columns, and either have each `Day` track what `Week` and `WeekDay` it belongs to, or have a converter figure out those values for me. Then I could bind those values to `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` in my `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`

So my `Day` object would look like:

```
public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Of course, these should implement the usual PropertyChange Notifications
    public int WeekNo {get; set;}
    public int WeekDay {get; set;}
    public DateTime  Date {get; set;}
}
```

and I would have an `ObservableCollection<Day> Days` in my ViewModel, which would be bound in the XAML with this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding WeekNo}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I wrote some examples on how to use an ItemsControl [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) if you're interested

Comment: So I could maybe make 7 integer days(Sunday->Saturday) but I'm blurry on how you said I could track what weekday(week) it belongs to or how I could make a converter. Also what is itemspanelTemplate? I'm sorry for the ignorance, but this is all new to me especially binding. :) Thanks for the input btw.

Comment: @TMan See the link I posted for an example of the ItemsControl and how it works. It will loop through a collection and draw each item one at a time to the screen. The `ItemsPanelTemplate` is the container that holds all the items, while the `ItemContainerStyle` is the style applied to all the items. You can also use the `ItemTemplate` to tell WPF how to draw each item.

Comment: Scratch the itemspaneltemplate..just seen that answer on your blog.

Comment: @TMan I also added a sample Day class to my answer. You can use C#'s Date functions to get DayOfWeek, and you can probably use `Math.Floor(Date.Day / 7)` to get the WeekNo

Comment: Thanks for all the input I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: Do I need INotifyPropertyChanged
What is this used for?

Comment: @TMan It is used to automatically update the UI when the value changes. If the value never changes, you don't need it, but if you ever change the value then you will need to implement that interface