# WPF ListBox with self-removing items

Tags: wpf, button, listbox

I am trying to set up a listbox where users can remove items by clicking on each value they want to remove.
I set up the style for my listbox (DisplayName is a member of the item class) in orderto include a button for each item:

```
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
              <Button Content="[x]" />
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now I am having trouble trying to set the button to delete the associated entry. 
Can anybody point a way?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the ListBox binding and get

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend you use an ICommand and pass the selected item of the listbox through a command parameter.

```
   <ListBox x:Name="MyListBoxName">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
             <Button Content="[x]" 
                     Command="{Binding ElementName=MyListBoxName, Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand}" 
                     CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
           </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

---

```
    public class YourViewModel
    {
       public ICommand DeleteItemCommand { get; set; }
       public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ListBoxDataSource { get; set; }

       public YourViewModel()
       {
          DeleteItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(DeleteItem);
       }

       private void DeleteItem(object item)
       {

       }
    }
```

Comment: Close, but your bindings are a bit off. The `DataContext` for the `ListBoxItem` will be an item in the collection, so you need to use a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding to find the `ListBox.DataContext` and get the DeleteCommand. It's much more practical than adding a `DeleteCommand` to every item in your list. I hope you don't mind, but I'm adjusting your code sample a bit to show this :)

Comment: Yes your right. I forgot about the reference hierarchy.

Comment: BTW, idk if you remember me but you answered one my questions a long time ago when I was still desperate rookie hoping to learn. Let me tell you I've come a LONNNGG way since then. :) You kind of helped lay the foundation for me and it has paid off big time for me. Thanks for all your help and help to others on stack overflow. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905920/making-a-customized-schedule-in-wpf

Comment: I do remember you TMan, we went into a private chat to talk about one of your posts if I recall correctly. I've seen some good answers from you recently (think I may have upvoted one or two), and am glad to see you're now comfortable enough with WPF to be helping other newbies too :)