# How to properly remove Items from a ListView when the ItemTemplate is a User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I tried to follow the example here:

[WPF ListBox with self-removing items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770440/wpf-listbox-with-self-removing-items)

It made sense but my issue was, the ListView itself is determining the template used. So it can easily customise the bindings to point to the correct target. I am however using MVVM and am struggling to fit the two together.

Example, if the template was:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <local:MyItemView/>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This suddenly becomes more difficult, as ideally, I want to reuse that view without hard coding the bindings.

I tried to use `DependencyProperty` to pass the `List` and the `Element` through, so I could delete it via  command.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate Name="myList">
      <DataTemplate>
          <local:MyItemView TheList={Binding ElementName=myList, Path=DataContext.List} TheElement={Binding}/>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

However, I had binding errors telling me that it couldn't convert the value for `TheElement` from `MyClassViewModel` to `MyClass`. Even if I commented that out `TheList` was always NULL.

Essentially I want:

```
class MyDataClass { // pretend there's more here}

class MyDataClassContainer
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataClass> Items;
    public void Add(MyDataClass);
    public void Remove(MyDataClass);
}

class MyDataClassEntryViewModel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TheClass", typeof(MyDataClass), typeof(MyDataClassEntryViewModel));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListContainerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TheContainer", typeof(MyDataClassContainer), typeof(MyDataClassEntryViewModel));

    public MyDataClass TheClass;
    public MyDataClassContainer TheContainer;
    public ICommand Delete = new DelegateCommand(RemoveItem);

    private function RemoveItem(object parameter)
    {
        TheContainer.Remove(TheClass);
    }
}
```

With the following templates:

MyDataClassEntryView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=Delete}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyDataContainerView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Container.Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyDataClassEntryView TheClass="{Binding}" TheContainer="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=DataContext.Container}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Note: I have omitted most of the superfluous lines, as I'm trying to get a generic answer I can use everywhere. Not a hard coded single solution. I was basically want to keep the MVVM structure strong, without lots of hard coded and wiring in the background. I want to use the XAML as much as possible.

All the other methods I see to do with removing from a list, require all sorts of assumptions, such as using the SelectedIndex/Item, or using a method on the ContainerView itself to take the element as a parameter, cast it, then remove, etc. In short, most solutions are far too hard coded to the given examples. It feels like there should be an easy way to achieve this in WPF.

As the ListView issautomatically creating instances of my sub-ViewModel/Views, it's impossible for me to get any data in apparently. I just want to pass parameters along using bindings, basically.

Answer (score 2):

Your button should look like this:

```
<Button Content="Delete" 
        Command="{Binding Path=Delete}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}/>
```

Then the remove command should look something like this:

```
private function RemoveItem(object parameter)
    {
        var item = parameter as MyDataClass
        if(item != null)
            TheContainer.Remove(item);
    }
```

You do not need to pass the list to the UserControl within the ItemTemplate, since it doesn't need to know about the list at all

Edit:
I read over your question a few times to see what you were confused about so I will try to clarify.

Whether the ListView sets its own template in the Xaml, or you use another UserControl, the datacontext still gets passed down to the item. Regardless of how you decide to template the items, the ItemTemplate will have the datacontext of a single item from the ListView's items list.

I think your confusion comes in with having controls outside being brought in for templating. Think of it as if the Xaml from the control you brought in being cut and pasted into the DataTemplate of the ListView when running the program, and then it is really no different from being hard coded in there.

Comment: Right, that does make sense. I think my initial issue was that I was referencing the parent elements by Name from within the templated User Controls. However, I can just use the Hierarchy/Ancestor search instead. My only issue with your suggestion at the moment is, TheContainer is still being passed as null and I'm not sure why!

Comment: @mGuv in the code you posted you never initialize it. Make sure you initialize it at some point, typically the class constructor

Comment: well I was hoping to Bind it through the template but it didn't work. How can I do it via the constructor if it is called automatically by the ListView? I don't have control there to pass the List in to the Constructor?

Comment: Binding just hooks into existing data structures. The variables you bind to have to be initialized to some object other than null for the binding to properly work.

Comment: The container is already created before the ListView. I have some other controls to Add things to the list, and that works and causes the ListView to update - the items in the list view though, have a null reference even with binding. I must have the binding wrong somehow.

Comment: Could you edit you question with your current code? I might be able to help you some more then

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reach outside of a DataTemplate with Element bindings like you have tried.

Instead you need to use a relativesource like this.

```
<local:MyItemView TheList="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.List}" />
```

Comment: Hmm, even then I am still seeing `null` in my ViewModel