# UWP - MVVM - Remove ListView item using ItemTemplate button

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp, listviewitem

I have a screen displaying a list of items on which the user can click a button to remove the corresponding item from the list.

I am trying to do so using MVVM.

But the item is not aware of the containing list when it gets the action.
I saw some answers here and there, but none of them using out of the box MVVM features I have in my environment
For example that one using PRISM (don't know if I should use that too, is it standard?):

- [How to properly remove Items from a ListView when the ItemTemplate is a User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917930/how-to-properly-remove-items-from-a-listview-when-the-itemtemplate-is-a-user-con?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ItemClass.Property01, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding RemoveItemCommand}" >
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Cancel" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And here is the ModelView list:

```
private static ObservableCollection<ItemClass> _MyItemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass> {
    new ItemClass{ Property01 = "Sometext" }
};
public ObservableCollection<ItemClass> MyItemList { get { return _MyItemList; } }
```

And I want to be able to perform the following (the example of code from the main model view, I could create an item model view if necessary for solving):

```
public IMvxCommand RemoveItemCommand { get; private set; }
public MyViewModel(IUserDialogs dialogs)
{
    RemoveItemCommand = new MvxCommand(RemoveItem);
}
public void RemoveItem(object theItem) { MyItemList.Remove(theItem); }
```

Comment: If the list item is not aware of hte list, you got two options: Use Routing events to make the Container (wich references the list) to be handle the click | Make the item aware of the list. I do not think you need to do anything special. Asuming you wrote no code to re-use the ViewModel instances, once the Item goes out of scope it will not keep the list in memory. Circular references are not that unusual in .NET However there might be a better way I am not aware off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `x:Name="listView"` attribute to your ListView, then in the template

```
<Button Grid.Column="1"
    Command="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
```

However, when I face problems like this, I usually just use code behind instead. The reason for that, I can use debugger for C# code in visual studio, but debugging these complex bindings is much harder. Here’s a C# version, the code is IMO cleaner, and easier to debug:

```
void removeItem_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    object i = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
    ( this.DataContext as MyViewModel )?.RemoveItem( i );
}
```

Or maybe that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a context menu item on the list view (or a delete button on the page somewhere) to delete the currently selected item(s). You can then get the selection from the list view.

Alternatively you could attach the context menu to the list view item in PrepareContainterForItemOverride (and detach it in the other Override method)

That would be a more standards interaction style.

If you must have the button inside the list view item, then the easiest way to get the list item would probably be to use a visual tree helper to go up from the button to the list view item and then get the actual item from the list view item.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the hints,
Using Soonts answer, I was able to develop a fast solution,

Here is what the final implementation looks like for reference for whoever wants to copy/paste/adapt (note I did not test code as I replaced variables/functions names):

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemClass_ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ItemClass.Property01, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding ElementName=ItemClass_ListView, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Cancel" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IMvxCommand RemoveItemCommand { get; private set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // Initializing Commands
        RemoveItemCommand = new MvxCommand<ItemClass>(OnRemoveItemClick);
    }

    public void OnRemoveItemClick(ItemClass anItem)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<ItemClass> _MyItemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass> {
        new ItemClass(),
        new ItemClass()
    };

    public ObservableCollection<ItemClass> MyItemList
    {
        get { return _MyItemList; }
    }
}
```